# Error en el Servlet en Java NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, web

Me sale este Error

[image: Error en el Servlet]

El formulario HTML

[image: El Formulario en HTML]

El Codigo del Servlet

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package SERVLET;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author jc
 */
@WebServlet(name = "registrar", urlPatterns = {"/registrar"})
public class registrar extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet registrar</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet registrar at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         String dni,nombre,apellido,fecha,direccion,distrito;
        
        dni=request.getParameter("txtdni");
        nombre=request.getParameter("txtnombre");
        apellido=request.getParameter("txtapellido");
        fecha=request.getParameter("txtfecha");
        direccion=request.getParameter("txtdireccion");
        distrito=request.getParameter("txtdistrito");
        
        if (!dni.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !nombre.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !apellido.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !fecha.equalsIgnoreCase("") &&!direccion.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !distrito.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            DATOS.datospersona fun=new DATOS.datospersona();
            ENTIDAD.ePersona ent=new ENTIDAD.ePersona(dni, nombre, apellido, fecha, direccion, distrito);
            
            if (fun.RegistrarPersona(ent))
            {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Hola.jsp");
            }
            else
            {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

EL CODIGO HTML

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Registro</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="center-block">Introduzca los Datos del nuevo Socio</h1>
            <form action="registrar" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                Dni <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtdni"/><br> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                NOMBRE <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtnombre"/><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                APELLIDOS <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtapellido"/><br>
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Fecha Nacimiento <input class="form-control" type="date" name="txtfecha"/><br>  
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Direccion <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtdireccion"/><br>  
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Distrito <select  class="form-control"  type="text" NAME="txtdistrito" SIZE=1> 
                <OPTION>SJL</OPTION>
                <OPTION >RIMAC</OPTION>
                <OPTION >ATE</OPTION>
                <OPTION >SANTA ANITA</OPTION> 
                </SELECT> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" value="aceptar">Registrar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por convención, las clases deben ir la primera con mayuscula, y los paquetes todo en minúscula. He probado tu código y funciona

Comment: :D Lo hice y me funciono gracias por tu ayuda DANI se te agradece solo era cambiar cambiarles mayúsculas a minúsculas